# How can I install, using apt, python3 with zlib? Or cani I not use apt for this?

Tags: apt, python3, zlib

I have installed python2 and python3 using apt.

I have tried to use

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 testenv1
```

and get

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zlib
ImportError: No module named 'zlib'
```

I have searched, as

```
$ sudo find / -name 'libz.*'
[sudo] password for x: 
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/snap/core/7917/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/snap/core/7917/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
/snap/core/7713/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/snap/core/7713/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
/snap/core18/1144/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/snap/core18/1144/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
/snap/core18/1192/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
/snap/core18/1192/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
```

Is there a way to use apt to install python3 with zlib?

If not, would you please point me to clear instructions on how to proceed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Use apt's *search* feature

```
$ apt search python3 zlib

Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
python3-netcdf4/disco 1.4.2-1build1 amd64
  Python 3 interface to the netCDF4 (network Common Data Form) library
```

Step 2: Use apt's *show* feature to determine if it's the package you really want.

```
$ apt show python3-netcdf4

Package: python3-netcdf4
Version: 1.4.2-1build1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/python
Source: netcdf4-python
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian GIS Project <pkg-grass-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 1,599 kB
Depends: python3 (<< 3.8), python3 (>= 3.7~), python3-cftime, python3-numpy (>= 1:1.14.3), python3-numpy-abi9, python3:any, libc6 (>= 2.14), libhdf5-103, libnetcdf13 (>= 1:4.4.0)
Homepage: http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/
Download-Size: 476 kB
APT-Sources: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 Packages
Description: Python 3 interface to the netCDF4 (network Common Data Form) library
 NetCDF version 4 has many features not found in earlier versions of the
 library and is implemented on top of HDF5. This module can read and write
 files in both the new netCDF 4 and the old netCDF 3 format, and can create
 files that are readable by HDF5 clients. The API is modelled after
 Scientific.IO.NetCDF, and should be familiar to users of that module.
 .
 Most new features of netCDF 4 are implemented, such as multiple unlimited
 dimensions, groups and zlib data compression. All the new numeric data types
 (such as 64 bit and unsigned integer types) are implemented. Compound and
 variable length (vlen) data types are supported, but the enum and opaque data
 types are not. Mixtures of compound and vlen data types (compound types
 containing vlens, and vlens containing compound types) are not supported.
 .
 This package contains the netCDF 4 module for Python 3.
```

If none of the apt packages provide what you want, then start looking at pip packages.

Comment: Thank you! I have done what you suggested, and I suppose "Most new features of netCDF 4 are implemented, such as...zlib data compression" and "This pac age contains the netCDF 4 module for Python 3" indicate that this package is what I need. Is the apt search on my laptop, or the internet? Should I $ sudo apt install python3-netcdf4?